# Loading & Freezing a Pretrained Model to Combine with a New Network

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a pretrained model and would like to build a classifier on top of it. I’m trying to load and freeze the weights of the pretrained model, and pass its outputs to the new classifier, which I’d like to optimise. Here is what I have so far, I’m a little stuck on a `TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'` error from the `nn.Sequential` line:

```
import model #model.py contains the architecture of the pretrained model

class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def forward(self, x):
        ...

net = model.Model()
net.load_state_dict(checkpoint["net"])

for c in net.children():
    for param in child.parameters():
        params.requires_grad = False

model = nn.Sequential(nn.ModuleList(net()), Classifier())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue after a discussion with @ptrblck from the PyTorch Forums. The solution is similar to Shai's answer, only that because `net` contains an instance of the `model.Model` class, one should do `model = nn.Sequential(net, Classifier())` instead, without calling `nn.ModuleList()`.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```py
model = nn.Sequential(nn.ModuleList(net), Classifier())
```

---

You are "calling" `net.forward` by `net()`, as opposed to the `__init__` method of `Classifier` *class* in `Classifier()`.